# Example applications that use the following windows APIs

Tags: windows, ipc, file-sharing

Does anybody know any windows applications that use windows API like CreateNamedPipe, CreateFileMapping, CreateMailSlot? Googling didn't help!

Comment: Your edit ("XYZ How does WLZ work in linux?") made this question, as well as all the existing answers, meaningless -- if you have a new question, please ask it separately (and be more specific!).

Answer (score 1):

You can find an [example of CreateNamedPipe here](http://www.codersource.net/win32/named-pipes/createnamedpipe-creating-named-pipe-server.aspx)

You can find an [example of CreateFileMapping here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647051/error-using-createfilemapping-c)

You can find an [example of CreateMailSlot here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365785.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Google *should* help.

There's also tons of sample code that comes with Visual Studio.

Here's a link I got from Googling "createfilemapping example":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Here's one from Googling "win32 createnamedpipe example":

http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:win32_createnamedpipe_example:txt